# Finding the fourth moment of $n$ i.i.d. random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have $X_1 \ldots X_n$ random variables that are i.i.d. We know that $E(X_1) = 0, E(X_1^2) = a, E(X_1^3) = b, E(X_1^4) = c$.

Let $$Y = \frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n}$$

what is the fourth moment of $Y$?

Now I tried to calculate this by using some linearity and then somehow applying multinomial theorem. When applying multinomial theorem, I use the fact that we only need to consider the terms $X_i^4$ of which there are $n$ of them and the terms $6X_i^2X_j^2$, since the other terms will contain $X_i$ and we know $E(X_i) = 0$. The problem is I don't know how to calculate how many of the latter kind of term exist? How should I do that.

Comment: Even if $n=1$ we can't do it, which raises the question of what the problem source expected you to do. Maybe they want the general case in terms of the $n=1$ case, but then they'd write e.g. $E(X_1^4)=c$. Maybe they want an asymptotic result, but again that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Apologies, a typo. Forgot to write $E(X_1^4) = c$. @J.G.

Comment: Do we know 4th moment of $X_1$? I think you need this.

Comment: @Muselive yes, my bad, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ${n\choose 2}=\frac12n(n-1)$ terms of the form $6X_i^2X_j^2$ with $i \not=j$

Comment: I suspect the answer is actually $\frac{c+3(n-1)a^2}{n^3}$.  If you divided this by the square of the variance of $Y$, i.e. by $\frac{a^2}{n^2}$, you would get $\frac{c}{na^2} +3\frac{n-1}{n}$ which converges towards $3$ as $n$ increases, the kurtosis of a normal distribution, as you might expect from the central limit theorem